# How to interpret ARIMA(0,1,0)?

Tags: arima, interpretation, random-walk

I ran the `auto.arima()`command in R on a set of data and it chose the appropriate model to be ARIMA(0,1,0).

I know ARIMA(0,0,0) is just white noise, but what does ARIMA(0,1,0) mean?

Comment: ARIMA(0,1,0) is random walk.

Comment: @RichardHardy I try to look online before posting a question. Post the comment as an answer. Its good to have a reference

Answer (score 15, accepted):

ARIMA(0,1,0) is random walk.

It is a cumulative sum of an i.i.d. process which itself is known as ARIMA(0,0,0).

Comment: a bit short as an answer

Comment: @g3o2, the real answer is in the first line. To make it artificially longer, I have added the second line. (OK, this is a joke. The second line gives the definition of a random walk.) I gave the name and the definition, and that was sufficient for the OP. I do believe in the virtue of brevity. There is plenty of information online on random walk, and the purpose of Cross Validated is not to duplicate it.

Comment: "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better." (quoted from CV help)

Comment: @g3o2, thank you. I think my answer is full already (even the first line is a full answer), so there is no tradeoff between completeness and brevity anymore. But I appreciate the tip and I will see if I can add something that is still relevant without expanding into unrelated topics.

Comment: @g3o2, From a [highly-upvoted answer](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4641/if-a-complete-answer-is-short-should-it-be-a-comment) on Meta: *If it answers the question in a self-contained way, I don't think an answer's length particularly matters. For very short answers, it would be nice if the answerer provided a bit of "bonus" information (background, support for their answer, etc), but I think this extra effort should be more of a social norm than a hard and fast rule.* I will try my best at that bonus information :)

Comment: @RichardHardy Is there a change I can make to test1 = arima(as.ts(df$x), order = c(0,1,0)) to add a drift constant?

Comment: @Remy, have you tried [`Arima`](http://127.0.0.1:19725/library/forecast/html/Arima.html) from the `forecast` package with option `include.drift=TRUE` or `include.constant=TRUE`?

Comment: @RichardHardy Thanks, it worked!

Answer (score 8):

An ARIMA(0, 1, 0) series, when differenced once, becomes an ARMA(0, 0), which is random, uncorrelated, noise.

If $X_1, X_2, X_3, \ldots$ are the random variables in the series, this means that

$$X_{i+1} - X_{i} = \epsilon_{i + 1}$$

where $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2, \ldots$ is a sequence of centered, uncorrelated random variables.

Rearranging

$$ X_{i+1} = X_i + \epsilon_i $$

reveals that we have a random walk.

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate it in R quite easily:

```
plot(arima.sim(model = list(order=c(0,1,0)),n=1000))
```

The result obtained is:
[image: ARIMA of order c(0,1,0)]
We observe that this plot is reminiscent of a Random Walk of order 1.