# ARIMA Valid combinations ARIMA(0,1,0)x(0,0,0)

Tags: python, arima

Is ARIMA(0,1,0)x(0,0,0) a valid grid search combination using Sarimax in Python? I've built a few ARIMA models in python and have noticed that this combination is not found in the grid search so it leaves me wondering if this a valid combination.  Obviously, I'm not an expert but was looking for some additional information.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I think you need to provide more context for your question for people to give you more constructive help.

Comment: ARIMA (0,1,0) is a random walk. See [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/310353/how-to-interpret-arima0-1-0)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it is, in particular if you force a non-seasonal model. [Python: auto_arima predicts constant value](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/529827/1352) gives an example where `auto_arima()` chooses an ARIMA(0,1,0) random walk.