# Python: auto_arima predicts constant value

Tags: python, forecasting, arima

As a newbie, I am trying to implement the forecast using the auto Arima model. After searching, I found this [site](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/time-series/arima-model-time-series-forecasting-python/) illustrates the usage and the hyperparameters used in the model. However, when I tried to forecast, the model gave me an array of constants.

Please advise if I asked in the wrong place. Thanks.

The data is a simple 29 days data:

```
daily_infect = [ 15,  11,  21,  25,  32, 186, 204, 334, 242, 274, 294, 315, 722,
       453, 594, 536, 640, 672, 557, 489, 358, 351, 330, 548, 582, 474,
       506, 325, 214]
```

Here is the code:

```
# reference: https://alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/modules/generated/pmdarima.arima.auto_arima.html
import pmdarima as pm
model = pm.auto_arima(daily_infect,
                      start_p=2, start_q=2, # default=2
                      test='kpss',       # default=kpss
                      max_p=5, # default=5 
                      max_q=2, # default=2
                      m=1,              # Note that if m == 1 (i.e., is non-seasonal)
                      d=None,           # If None (by default), the value will automatically be selected based on the results of the test
                      seasonal=False,   # No Seasonality
                      start_P=1,        # default=1
                      D=None,           # The order of the seasonal differencing. If None (by default, the value will automatically be selected based on the results of the seasonal_test
                      trace=True,
                      error_action='warn',  # default=warn
                      stepwise=True)    # The stepwise algorithm can be significantly faster than fitting all (or a random subset of) hyper-parameter combinations and is less likely to over-fit the model.

print(model.summary())
```

I ran the diagnose. It seems okay

```
model.plot_diagnostics(figsize=(15,8))
plt.show()
```

[image: diagonose]

Here is the forecast code:

```
# Forecast
n_days = 10
fc = model.predict(n_periods=n_days)
index_of_fc = np.arange(len(daily_infect), len(daily_infect)+n_days)

# make series for plotting purpose
fc_series = pd.Series(fc, index=index_of_fc)

# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,9))
ax.plot(daily_infect)
ax.plot(fc_series, color='red')

ax.set_title("Final Forecast")
ax.figure.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image: The constant prediction]

What I've tried is to change some parameters back to default, but no luck. Is there's anything I can improve? Thanks.

Comment: What else would you expect it to predict? There is no trend, no cyclic changes...

Comment: What I think is that the model predicts based on the lags (AR), and the error of the lagged forecast (MR). Is it necessary to have cyclic changes to forecast? Thanks.

Comment: All time-series models are about seeking patterns in data, i.e. trends, or cycles that periodically repeat, otherwise, what would they use as a base for making a forecast..? If there are no cycles and no trend, you don't know what will come next.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Understood.

Comment: Please provide *working* code. As in: your code should run in a new Python console (assuming modules are installed). Also, Tim is absolutely right. You may want to look through [previous questions on flat ARIMA forecasts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=arima+flat). Or at [Is it unusual for the MEAN to outperform ARIMA?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/124955/1352)

Comment: @StephanKolassa thanks! I'll look into it and add the code.

Comment: I'll happily take a look at your question and bring some knowledge about ARIMA to the table, but being a complete Python n00b, your call to `array` is what threw me off. If you make it easy for people to help you, you will get better answers.

Comment: @StephanKolassa the code should work now. Thank you.

Comment: Series look like a random walk to me. What output do you get on `print(model.summary())`?

Comment: @DanielR I'll add the result as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what your call to `pm.auto_arima()` writes to the console:

```
Best model:  ARIMA(0,1,0)(0,0,0)[0]
```

That is, it fits a non-seasonal (that's the trailing `(0,0,0)[0]` part, and it's not surprising, since you specified `seasonal=False`) ARIMA(0,1,0) model. This is an ARMA(0,0) model on first differences, or

$$ By_t = y_t-y_{t-1} = \epsilon_t, $$

where $B$ is the backshift operator, and $\epsilon_t\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$. Alternatively,

$$ y_t=y_{t-1}+\epsilon_t. $$

That is, a random walk.

In forecasting, you substitute the expected value for the innovations $\epsilon_t$, which is zero. Thus, your forecasts are simply the last observation. In particular, the forecasts do not vary over time, so you get a flat line.

Now you will probably wonder why `auto_arima()` fits a random walk. As [Tim writes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/529827/python-auto-arima-predicts-constant-value#comment973302_529827), there is no obvious cycles or trends in your data, and the stepwise AIC optimization does not find meaningful autocorrelation or moving average dynamics in your time series. So `auto_arima()` indeed believes a random walk is the best description of your data.

You may want to look through [previous questions on flat ARIMA forecasts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=arima+flat). Or at [Is it unusual for the MEAN to outperform ARIMA?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/124955/1352) A flat forecast - whether from the overall average, as discussed in the last link, or whether from a random walk model - is surprisingly often the best forecast you can make. If there is no structure to be found, then there is no structure to be found.

I recommend the excellent free online book [*Forecasting: Principles and Practice* (2nd ed.) by Athanasopoulos & Hyndman](https://otexts.org/fpp2/). It uses R, not Python, but it's very good, accessible, and free.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive explanation and other references.